# Avoid concurrent accessible for piece of code in server

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, parallel-processing

I want to avoid concurrent accessible for piece of code in my server side business logic.
my business class is not a static class. Service layer is implemented in wcf .Any suggestion?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to give anything but vague suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use some kind of synchronization mechanism. The simplest is the [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) statement:

```
class BusinessLogic
{
    // To avoid the possibility of a deadlock, prevent external code from
    // ever acquiring this lock by making the lock target private.
    private readonly object lockTarget = new object();

    void Foo()
    {
        lock(lockTarget)
        {
            // your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Of course thread synchronization in general is a complex topic, and the correct or best solution can only be reached after considering the particular context. There are other synchronization primitives in the [`System.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx) namespace that you should also be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Question needs bit of editing to clearly mention where is business logic which you want to restrict concurrent access for, is it part of wcf side?

Also which concurrency mode of wcf you have configured your wcf for as of now?

I assume code which your want to control access for is part of wcf side, with that assumption, as your class is not static, then only way to restrict concurrent access is through various locking mechanism provided in .net.

check on locking in C# and see which one best suits for your locking needs (how much thread safety you need).

also can check this discussion, it will give you some directions on what you need basically:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f82f9cd8-87d6-4a4e-9e03-5dd2d143c680/wcf-service-concurrency-lock-right-way-to-do